# Using a smart contract table. How can I query a row using another field instead of the primary key id?

Tags: smart-contract, table, contract-development

How can I query a smart contract table to return a row instead of using the primary key id?

I have the following: https://jungle.bloks.io/account/mybest111111?loadContract=true&tab=Tables&account=mybest111111&scope=mybest111111&limit=100

I want to return the row based on the asset_id. I'm doing this in C++ contract code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all please consult the multi-index table documentation:

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/how-to-guides/multi-index/index

in your question you say you want to query the table without using the primary key and later you say you want to query it based on asset_id; but it seems asset_id is your primary key. I assume this is a typo and you want to query based on any other field BUT asset_id.

in this case you have to create a secondary index and query the table using it.

see this doc page on how to define a secondary index:

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/how-to-guides/multi-index/how-to-define-a-secondary-index

and this page on how to use a secondary index:
https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/how-to-guides/multi-index/how-to-iterate-and-retrieve-a-multi_index-table-based-on-secondary-index